# Next.js Caching Issue?

Tags: debugging, caching, next.js

**Next version: 12.3.4**

**Goal:**

- Have scripts conditionally injected into _document.js depending on a cookie value

**Observations:**

- With non-production builds all works as a expected; client-side, that cookie is set after a user action, a page reload is triggered, and document.js injects, or not injects, the scripts based on that cookies value as expected
- With the production build, document.js doesn't seem to recognize the changed cookie value until after the third refresh

**Question:**

- What could account for the variation in production behavior?